# How do I use VBA Code to paste value in active cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write VBA code to have the user select a file, once file is selected the VBA code will copy a value (whatever is in J3 of the selected file) and paste to the active cell of the tracker.

I have code (shared below), when I identify a specific cell for the value to paste to, the macro runs just fine - no problem; however, when I change to ActiveCell (right now the active cell is N3 of the tracker), it errors out. Can someone please share what's wrong with the code?

I can't use a specific cell as this is for a tracker so as new rows are added the cell to paste the value to will change.

*code leveraged from XelPlus YouTube video

I've also tried Range(ActiveCell.Address) but when I do that it returns the value but to the first cell of the next row.

This is the code that is not working as I was expecting:

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your evaluation template", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("J3").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FY24 Evaluations").Range(ActiveCell.Address).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ActiveCell` is a `Range` object that represents the active cell in the active window.
- `ActiveCell` is changed after opening a new workbook. Use `rCell` to save the range object reference.
- Assign value to a cell is more efficient than `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.ActiveCell property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm183074)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant, rCell As Range
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rCell = ActiveCell
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your evaluation template", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        rCell.Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("J3").Value
        OpenBook.Close False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```